# Nginx how to setup custom error page with css

Tags: nginx

I've setup custom error page but css is not loading both files are in same directory `C:/laragon/www/error/404.html` `C:/laragon/www/error/style.css`

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen 443 ssl default_server;
...
error_page 404 /404.html;
location = /404.html {
    root C:/laragon/www/error/;
    allow all;
    internal;
}
```

}

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    ...
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>

    <div id="notfound">
        <div class="notfound">
            <div class="notfound-404">
                <h1>Oops!</h1>
                <h2>404 - The Page can't be found</h2>
            </div>
            <a href="#">Go TO Homepage</a>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your static file `style.css` is not loaded from the `location` you show here, but from some other `location`. That's because the file actually exists, so it will not return a 404 error! It will be served like any other normal static file. Only the 404 page itself applies to this `location`.

How you choose to fix this depends on the remainder of your configuration and how you want to set up your filesystem. I recommend that you move the static file so that it is served with all your other static files.

Comment: but `404.html` has `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />` shouldn't it load css?

Comment: @UzairAli No, the CSS file does not return a 404!

Comment: so how can I make it load css with 404.html, do I have to embed css in html file?

Comment: No, you need to serve it normally.

Comment: sorry I just learned nginx so I don't know what you meant by serve it normally.

Comment: You serve it the same way as every other static file you are serving.